# Almacenar datos de en un array jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Estoy obteniendo datos de una tabla con el siguiente codigo

```js
$("#table_repuestos td").each(function(index) {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_repuestos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>DATO1</td>
      <td>DATO2</td>
      <td>DATO3</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>DATO11</td>
      <td>DATO22</td>
      <td>DATO33</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

¿De qué forma puedo almacenar todos los datos obtenidos en un arreglo?

EJEMPLO

```
var ParamObjSend = {                                                       
    'descripcion': 'DATO1',
    'codigo': 'DATO2',
    'Precio': 'DATO3',
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una Solución sería  *(explicación dentro del código)*

```js
 var array = [];
    /* Obtenemos todos los tr del Body*/
    var rowsBody= $("#table_repuestos").find('tbody > tr');
    /* Obtenemos todos los th del Thead */
    var rowsHead= $("#table_repuestos").find('thead > tr > th');
    
    /* Iteramos sobre as filas del tbody*/
    for (var i = 0; i < rowsBody.length; i++) {
        var obj={};/* auxiliar*/
        for (var j = 0;j < rowsHead.length;j++) /*  Iteramos sobre los th de THead*/
            /*Asignamos como clave el text del th del thead*/
             /*Asignamos como Valor el text del tr del tbody*/
            obj[rowsHead[j].innerText] =  rowsBody[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[j].innerText;
        array.push(obj);/* Añadimos al Array Principal*/
    }
    console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_repuestos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>Eliminar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>DATO1</td>
      <td>DATO2</td>
      <td>DATO3</td>
      <td>DATO4</td>
      <td>DATO5</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>DATO11</td>
      <td>DATO22</td>
      <td>DATO33</td>
      <td>DATO44</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es bastante sencillo, solo haz lo siguiente:

```js
// Creamos un objeto donde guardar primeramente las llaves
var obj = {};

// Creamos un arreglo donde guardar nuestros valores
var values = [];

// Recorremos todos los elementos th
$("#table_repuestos thead th").each(function(i, o) {

  // Obtenemos su respectivo texto
  var key = $(this).text(); 
  
  // Le asignamos como llave nuestro texto
  // y le damos un valor vacío
  obj[key] = '';

});

// Reocrremos todos los elementos td
$("#table_repuestos tbody td").each(function(i, o) {

  // Obtenemos su respectivo texto
  var value = $(this).text();
  // Agregamos nuestro valor al arreglo
  values.push(value);

});

var iterator = 0;

// Recorremos nuestro objeto
for(var key in obj){
  // Le asignamos el valor correspondiente
  obj[key] = values[iterator];
  iterator++;
}

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_repuestos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>Eliminar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>DATO1</td>
      <td>DATO2</td>
      <td>DATO3</td>
      <td>DATO4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> **Nota** El ejemplo anterior funcionará correctamente siempre y cuando el número de `TH` y `TD` sea exactamente igual

Comment: como lo tendría que hacer para almacenarlo con el nombre de su th ? edite la publicación gracias !

Comment: @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar He editado mi respuesta, revisala y cuentame si te soluciona tu problema

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me sirvió mucho, este codigo sirve solamente cuando tienes un solo tr en el body, como lo tendría que hacer si hubiera dos tr en body, editare mi pregunta gracias !